# jQuery calculate image background-position top position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-position

I set my images **centred** in CSS:

```
background-position: center center;
```

But I want to know its top-position now after it is set to centre, how can I calculate that with jQuery or just plain javaScript?

```css
.parallax3 {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/g/200/600');
  height: 100%;
}

.tagline {
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    letter-spacing:0.05em;
    padding: 25% 25%;
}

.grid-x {
    border:1px solid red;
}

.cell {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row widescreen">

  <div class="grid-container full">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-stretch small-padding-collapse">
      <div class="medium-6 cell">
        <div class="tagline text-center">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="medium-6 cell parallax-viewport">
        <div class="parallax3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/css/foundation.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Something like `$(".parallax3").position().top` wouldn't work? or am I missing something

Comment: @OmarEinea this will be related to positon of div not background

Comment: @OmarEinea it gets 0 which is not correct.

Comment: oh I see, position of the image itself!

Comment: as a first idea you need to find the formula .. the image is in the center, so it's center is in the center, so you move up from the center by height of image/2 minus the height of div/2 ... if the image is not overflowing it will be negative

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented above we need to find the formula, so the idea is to rely on the logic of `background-position:center` and `background-size:cover`. So since the image will always be stretched, we have two possibilities :

1. The top of the image will be the same as the top of div and thus **top=0**
2. The height of the image will be longer than the div and the top will be **hidden** and thus **top<0**

[image]

*As you may notice I considered the top position relatively to the top of the div which is the origin for me*

Now we need to consider all the different cases on how the image will **cover** the div and calculate the new height of the image depending on each situation.

**Here is a code example:**

```js
//am using fixed values because they are known in this case, so this need to also be calculated
var him = 600;
var wim = 200;
var ratio = him / wim;
/*--*/

function get_top() {
  var h = $('.parallax3').height();
  var w = $('.parallax3').width();

  var diffh = h - him;
  var diffw = w - wim;
  if (diffw > 0 && diffh > 0) {
    //the image is smaller than the div so it should get bigger by at least the max difference
    if (diffh > diffw*ratio) {
      //both height will be equal here so top position = 0
      console.log(0);
    } else {
      //height of image will be bigger so top position < 0
      var newH = (wim + diffw) * ratio;
      console.log((h - newH) / 2)
    }
  } else if (diffw > 0) {
    //only the width if div is bigger so the image width will stretch and the height will be bigger and top < 0;
    var newH = (wim + diffw) * ratio;
    console.log((h - newH) / 2)
  } else if (diffh > 0) {
    //only the height is bigger so the image height will stretch and both heights will be equal to div and top = 0
    console.log(0);
  } else {
    // the image is bigger in this case so we do same logic as the start with abs value but we will reduce size so we consider the lowest value
    if (Math.abs(diffh) < Math.abs(diffw)*ratio) {
      //both height will be equal here so top position = 0
      console.log(0);
    } else {
      //height of image will remain bigger so top position < 0
      var newH = (wim + diffw) * ratio;
      console.log((h - newH) / 2)
    }

  }
}

get_top();

$(window).resize(function() {
  get_top()
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.parallax3 {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/g/200/600');
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax3">
</div>
```

If we consider **contain** as value in background-size the image will always be contained inside the div so the two possibilities are:

1. The top of the image will be the same as the top of the div and thus **top=0**
2. The image will be smaller in height and the top of image will be **visible** and thus **top>0**

[image]

Same thing as the above, we need to consider the different situations and calculate the new height of the image.

**Here is a code example:**

```js
//am using fixed values because they are known in this case, so this need to also be calculated
var him = 600;
var wim = 200;
var ratio = him / wim;
/*--*/

function get_top() {
  var h = $('.parallax3').height();
  var w = $('.parallax3').width();
  var diffh = h - him;
  var diffw = w - wim;
  if (diffw > 0 && diffh > 0) {
    //the image is smaller than the div so it should get bigger by at least the min difference
    if (diffh < diffw*ratio) {
      //both height will be equal here so top position = 0
      console.log(0);
    } else {
      //height of image will be bigger so top position < 0
      var newH = (wim + diffw) * ratio;
      console.log((h - newH) / 2)
    }
  } else if (diffw > 0) {
    //only the width if div is bigger so the image height need to be reduced and both height will be equal
    console.log(0);

  } else if (diffh > 0) {
    //only the height is bigger so the image width will be reduced 
    var newH = (wim + diffw) * ratio;
    console.log((h - newH) / 2);
  } else {
    // the image is bigger in this case so we do same logic as the start with abs value but we will reduce size so we consider the biggest value
    if (Math.abs(diffh) > Math.abs(diffw)*ratio) {
      //both height will be equal here so top position = 0
      console.log(0);
    } else {
      //height of image will be bigger so top position < 0
      var newH = (wim + diffw) * ratio;
      console.log((h - newH) / 2)
    }

  }
}

get_top();

$(window).resize(function() {
  get_top()
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.parallax3 {
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/g/200/600');
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax3">
</div>
```

*Both snippet can be optimized to reduce redundancy but I kept them like this to better explain different situations.*

Comment: @laukok the original size of the image you used as background :) since it's know i used these value, but we can make the dynamic too

Comment: got it. so I need to get the image sizes first! :-)

Comment: @laukok yes but i think this part is easier ;)

Comment: @laukok so let me know if it works well in your case and if the value are correct ;)

Comment: @laukok i found some mistake in my logic, so updated my code :)

Comment: thanks for the update and the detailed answer. the figures seem correct. thanks! :-)